# Scroll an UITextView inside an UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview

I've an UITextView into an UITableViewCell, but I can't scroll the text. When I try to scroll the textView, the tableView catch the touches.

There is any way to fix this?

PS: Subclass of UITableViewController

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking you can detect the object being touched and if it is a UITextView, then temporarily disable scrolling with UITableView:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
     [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
     UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

     //detect if touch is on UITextView
     if ([touch.view isKindOfClass: UITextView.class]) {
         yourTableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
     }
}
```

Don't forget to re-enable scrolling of the UITableView afterwards in touchesEnded

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        yourTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunally as far as I know, and as far as I tried, touched* doesn't get called into UITableViewController

Comment: Yes, you're right, didn't know you were using UITableViewController. You would have to subclass UITableViewController or just create a UIViewController and throw a TableView within the view. Both ways should capture touch if you choose to do so.

Comment: Actually I'm subclassing UITableViewController